# How to sum values inside array of hash with same keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to sum the values of same keys like

```
arr = [{"69120090" => [1, 2, 3]}, {"69120090" => [4, 5, 6]}]
```

I need to result in:

```
result = [{"69120090" => [5, 7, 9]}]
```

Comment: Please try a solution yourself first and let us know what you try

Comment: This looks easy but complex when you put lots of data in hash.

Comment: What about values with different keys? Should they also be merged or remain separately? i.e. can the result array contain more than 1 element? if so, please give a example.

Answer (score 7):

Reduce by [`Hash#merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) with a block:

```
arr = [{"69120090"=> [1, 2, 3] }, {"69120090"=> [4, 5, 6] }]
arr.each_with_object({}) do |h, acc|
  acc.merge!(h) { |_, v1, v2| v1.zip(v2).map(&:sum) }
end
#⇒ {"69120090"=>[5, 7, 9]}
```

The above accepts any number of hashes with any number of keys each.

Comment: or `arr.inject { |a, b| a.merge(b) { ... } }`

Comment: @Stefan I just thought it but now thinking why I followed so long way in my answer :|

Comment: @Stefan `merge!` should have better performance^W memory comsumption [in theory]. But yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have another option, given the array:

```
arr = [{ a: [1, 2, 3], b:[8,9,0] }, { a: [4, 5, 6], c: [1,2,3] }, { b: [0,1,2], c: [1,2,3] } ]
```

You could write:

```
tmp = Hash.new{ |k,v| k[v] = [] }
arr.each { |h| h.each { |k,v| tmp[k] << v } }
tmp.transform_values { |k| k.transpose.map(&:sum) }
```

Which returns

```
tmp #=> {:a=>[5, 7, 9], :b=>[8, 10, 2], :c=>[2, 4, 6]}
```

---

As one liner:

```
(arr.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |k,v| k[v] = [] }) { |h, tmp| h.each { |k,v| tmp[k] << v } }).transform_values { |k| k.transpose.map(&:sum) }
```